# R CMD check unsuccessful for R CUDA package

Tags: r, package, shared

I am trying to make a R CUDA package. I created a R package using package.skeleton. Then I wrote a configure.ac file in the package folder and created a src directory with CUDA code and Makefile.in files. I wrote in `NAMESPACE : useDynLib(cFunction)`.

The .so file is getting created in the package folder. When I am doing R CMD check , I get the following error:

```
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib) : 
  shared object ‘cFunction.so’ not found
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
```

I am unable to figure out what I am doing wrong here. I tried putting the .so file in libs folder in my package folder, in src folder of my package folder with no success. I also put the path of my package folder in LD_LIBRARY_PATH but still it did not work.

Also, if I use the package name is useDynLib then also it does not work.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

I would *strongly* recommend to look at an existing CUDA-using package such as [gputools](http://cran.r-project.org/package=gputools) or [WideLM](http://cran.r-project.org/package=WideLM).

Comment: I already looked at gputools package but could not understand where the gputools.so is so that I could keep my .so file also at the same place in my package.